# Comet Javascript error

Tags: javascript, json, orbited

I'm using Orbited as a Comet server on localhost. It is listening to ports:

```
9000 for http
61613 for stomp
```

My JavaScript debugger is reporting error: *JSON is not defined* in the line:

```
var vals = JSON.parse(payload);
```

What could be the cause and how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON library is not built into Javascript. You must include a [javascript JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). If you use the one I linked, your code should work.

Alternatively, since JSON is a subset of Javascript object literals, you may be able to do this:

```
var vals = eval('(' + payload + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a javascript include tag that loads the orbited json library in your html page

For your setup it will be located at http://:9000/static/JSON.js